# SSL problem with Fooman Speedster on PHP 5.6

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm using modman to handle the [Fooman Speedster](https://github.com/fooman/speedster) module. I have upgraded our Magento installation on our development server from **1.8.1.0** to **1.9.3.4**. When I tried to enable Fooman Speedster I got an SSL error. I tried to upgrade the Speedster module to the latest version (**3.0.15**), but the problem is still there. This is what I get if I try to enable Speedster:

```
<!-- language: logg -->
Selftest failed with: Step 1 - OK
Unable to Connect to ssl://mydomain.com:443. Error #0: 
Unable to Connect to ssl://mydomain.com:443. Error #0: 
Unable to Connect to ssl://mydomain.com:443. Error #0: 
Please read the manual for details.
Starting Fooman_Speedster_Model_Selftester
Default store loaded
Magento version: 1.9.3.4
Speedster DB version: Not installed
Speedster Config version: 3.0.15
Checking file locations
Checking rewrites
Checking database
Found file with extra whitespace trailing: /var/www/html/mydomain.com/.modman/Dibspw_Dibspw/app/code/community/Dibspw/Dibspw/Model/Observer.php
RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(/var/www/html/mydomain.com/.git): failed to open dir: Permission denied
Self-test finished
```

Running PHP version 5.6:

```
<!-- language: terminal -->
$ php -v
PHP 5.6.30-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Feb  8 2017 08:50:21) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

I don't know if it's relevant, but when I go to System - Configuration - Fooman Extensions/Support, I get the following in `var/log/system`:

```
<!-- language: logg -->
2017-09-11T08:24:47+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/default/default/template/fooman/common/selftester.phtml
```

## Update 1

The `Not valid template file`-problem above was fixed with [Symlinks cause ‘Not valid template file’ in Magento 1.9.3.4](https://tomlankhorst.nl/not-valid-template-file-magento-1-9-3-4-symlinks/)

## Update 2

The SSL problem was indeed a server configuration problem as suggested by @Kristof at Fooman. In my case, I was missing a CA certificate.

Now I get a new error message:

```
<!-- language: logg -->
Selftest failed with: Step 1 - OK
Step 2 - OK
Step 3 - OK
Step 4 - OK
Starting Fooman_Speedster_Model_Selftester
Default store loaded
Magento version: 1.9.3.4
Speedster DB version: Not installed
Speedster Config version: 3.0.15
Checking file locations
Checking rewrites
Checking database
Found file with extra whitespace trailing: /var/www/html/mydomain.com/.modman/Dibspw_Dibspw/app/code/community/Dibspw/Dibspw/Model/Observer.php
RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(/var/www/html/mydomain.com/.git): failed to open dir: Permission denied
Self-test finished
```

## Update 3

I have manually checked step 1-4 according to the [user manual](http://cdn.fooman.co.nz/media/custom/upload/InstructionsandTroubleshooting-FoomanSpeedster.pdf) and they work perfectly, just as the test output says. That makes me suspect the last lines in the end of the output: the `whitespace trailing` and the `RecursiveDictoryIterator`. But what can I do about that? I do not want to make the `.git`-directory available for the webserver and I don't want to edit the code of my modman modules...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension verifies a few things via the included selftest, including trying to connect to itself to see if the results pass the expected output.

It currently sounds likely that your server is configured in such a way that the server can't connect to itself via ssl. You can start debugging this by using `curl https://example.com` from the command line.

The code for the selftest itself can be found [here](https://github.com/fooman/speedster/blob/master/app/code/community/Fooman/Speedster/Model/Selftester.php#L22).

Comment: Indeed that seems to be the problem. `curl https://example.com` is working on my production server but not on my development server. I'll investigate it. Thanks for the push in the right direction!1

Comment: Do you have any guesses on the new problem? I'm not sure why it is failing now. I hope it is not because the `.git`-directory is not readable by the web server. I would rather not have that directory readable by the web server. Is there any way to tell Speedman to skip directories?

It complains about whitespace in modules. How would I handle this?

Comment: We can probably remove the check for malformed files for Speedster and/or don't recurse into hidden folders. For now I'd suggest changing https://github.com/fooman/common/blob/master/app/code/community/Fooman/Common/Model/Selftester.php#L206 to return true;

Comment: Or you could warn for malformed files, but not maybe fail. Failing for training whitespace seems a bit too strict, I doubt that will effect the minimization...

As for hidden folders, it would maybe be better to skip the folders that the current user (the web server user) does not have access to. It makes sense to scan the `.modman`-folder, but not the `.git`-folder.

Thanks for the help! I'll open an issue on the Speedster repository :)